# How can I set the docker image version automatically from github?

Tags: docker, dockerhub

I have link a github repo with my docker hub account. When there is a push to github `master` branch, a new image will be built in docker hub. But the image only has `LATEST` tag. How can I make the version increased automatically?

Ideally, I'd like it follow the sversion `1.0.0`. And increase for every push `1.0.1`, `1.0.2` `1.0.3` etc.

Is there a way to make it follow this pattern?

Answer (score 4):

You could associate a GitHub Action workflow to your repository, like [`docker/metadata-action`](https://github.com/docker/metadata-action)

> GitHub Action to extract metadata (tags, labels) for Docker. This action is particularly useful if used with [Docker Build Push action](https://github.com/docker/build-push-action).

You can [see it used here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66403227/6309). Warning: the tag name (as generated by the GitHub Action) will contain the branch name as well.

Answer (score 4):

I was having the same problem, solved with this GitHub Action Code:

1. Create a secret called **MAJOR** to save your mayor version
2. Create a secret called **MINOR** to save your minor version
3. You will need a token to update you repo secrets, so... create a secret called **REPO_ACCESS_TOKEN** to grant your action dose his work.

```
name: Docker Image CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:    
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    -
      name: Build the Docker image
      run: docker build . --file src/MasterReport.UI/Dockerfile --tag eriksongm/master-report:${{ secrets.MAJOR }}.${{ secrets.MINOR }}
    -
      name: Login to DockerHub
      uses: docker/login-action@v1 
      with:
        username: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_USERNAME }}
        password: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_TOKEN }}
    -
      name: Push to DockerHub
      run: docker push eriksongm/master-report:${{ secrets.MAJOR }}.${{ secrets.MINOR }}
    -
      name: Update Minor version
      uses: hmanzur/actions-set-secret@v2.0.0
      with:
        name: 'MINOR'
        value: $((${{ secrets.MINOR }}+1))
        repository: EriksonGM/MasterReport
        token: ${{ secrets.REPO_ACCESS_TOKEN }}
```

This was my final code, as you can see, I have a last step just to update the minor version, only if all the other jobs run ok.

Comment: worked for me. thank you!

Comment: This does not work. I get error trying to build docker image using the incremented tag. Error: buildx failed with: error: invalid tag "ghcr.io/my-company/my-repo:***.***": invalid reference format

Comment: @Mikolaj, can your share your code?

Comment: @EriksonGomes I added a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70925425/how-to-implement-semantic-versioning-in-github-actions-workflow

Comment: ```      - name: Autoincrement a new patch version
        run: |
          echo "NEW_PATCH_VERSION=$((${{ secrets.PATCH_VERSION }}+1))" >> $GITHUB_ENV```
Try setting the new patch version in a bash command like this.