# How to implement semantic versioning in GitHub Actions workflow?

Tags: docker, github, continuous-integration, github-actions, semantic-versioning

I would like to semantic versioning my docker images which are built and pushed to GitHub Container Registry by the GitHub Action.

I found a satisfying solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69059228/12877180

According to the solution I reproduced the following YAML.

```
name: Docker CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main ]

env:
  REGISTRY: ghcr.io

jobs:
  build-push:
    # needs: build-test
    name: Buid and push Docker image to GitHub Container registry
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      packages: write
      contents: read

    steps:
    - name: Checkout the repository
      uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Login to GitHub Container registry
      uses: docker/login-action@v1
      env:
        USERNAME: ${{ github.actor }}
        PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
      with:
        registry: ${{ env.REGISTRY }}
        username: ${{ env.USERNAME }}
        password: ${{ env.PASSWORD }}

    - name: Get lowercase repository name
      run: |
        echo "IMAGE=${REPOSITORY,,}">>${GITHUB_ENV}
      env:
        REPOSITORY: ${{ env.REGISTRY }}/${{ github.repository }}

    - name: Build and export the image to Docker
      uses: docker/build-push-action@v2
      with:
        context: .
        file: ./docker/Dockerfile
        target: final
        push: true
        tags: |
          ${{ env.IMAGE }}:${{ secrets.MAJOR }}.${{ secrets.MINOR }}
        build-args: |
          ENVIRONMENT=production

    - name: Update Patch version
      uses: hmanzur/actions-set-secret@v2.0.0
      with:
        name: 'MINOR'
        value: $((${{ secrets.MINOR }} + 1))
        repository: ${{ github.repository }}
        token: ${{ secrets.GH_PAT }}
```

Unfortunately this does not work.

The initial value of the `MINOR` secret is `0`. If the `build-push` job is executed very first time, the docker image is perfectly pushed to the `GHCR` with the `ghcr.io/my-org/my-repo:0.0` syntax.
The purpose of the `build-push` job is then increment the `MINOR` secret by `1`.

If the action job `build-push` is executed again after new event, I get error while trying to build docker image using the incremented tag.

```
/usr/bin/docker buildx build --build-arg ENVIRONMENT=production --tag ghcr.io/my-org/my-repo:***.*** --target final --iidfile /tmp/docker-build-push-HgjJR7/iidfile --metadata-file /tmp/docker-build-push-HgjJR7/metadata-file --file ./docker/Dockerfile --push .
error: invalid tag "ghcr.io/my-org/my-repo:***.***": invalid reference format
Error: buildx failed with: error: invalid tag "ghcr.io/my-org/my-repo:***.***": invalid reference format
```

Comment: Did you set the MAJOR value in your secrets? This assumes you don't want to use a more traditional solution like using the git tag to specify the container image tag.

Comment: Yes, the `MAJOR` secret is set to `0`. Thanks for the `git tag` suggestion. I need to checkout that `git tag` can be incremented automatically in CI process.

Comment: What are the current values of major and minor in your secrets? I've only ever manually incremented git tags, releases are a process that go through review, similar to reviewing whether each PR will be merged. But with the incremented tag, you can use that as the source of truth for tags on everything else GHA creates.

Answer (score 1):

You need to increment the version in a bash command like this:

```yaml
      - name: Autoincrement a new patch version
        run: |
          echo "NEW_PATCH_VERSION=$((${{ env.PATCH_VERSION }}+1))" >> $GITHUB_ENV
      - name: Update patch version
        uses: hmanzur/actions-set-secret@v2.0.0
        with:
          name: 'PATCH_VERSION'
          value: ${{ env.NEW_PATCH_VERSION }}
          repository: ${{ github.repository }}
          token: ${{ secrets.REPO_ACCESS_TOKEN }}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many semantic version github actions, those can be used based on individual's use case. Few work on the commit messages and other work on the branch name.

I have used https://github.com/marketplace/actions/semver-action which works on branching name and this supports for `trunk-based` and `git-flow` branching models

```
  - name: Calculate Semantic Version tag
    id: semver-tag
    uses: gandarez/semver-action@v2.0.0
    with:
      branching_model: "trunk-based"
      main_branch_name: "main"
      major_regex: "(?i)^(.+:)?(release/.+)"
      minor_regex: "(?i)^(.+:)?(feature/.+)"
      patch_regex: "(?i)^(.+:)?(hotfix/.+)"
      debug: "true"
```

It ouputs the semantic version and that can be used by any subsequent jobs to create a git tag for e.g. or a tag on docker image.

For e.g. below use the output from previous job and creats a tag

```
  - name:  Create Git Tag
    uses: rickstaa/action-create-tag@v1.7.2
    with:
      tag: ${{ steps.semver-tag.outputs.semver_tag }}
```

**Please Note:** This won't work if your PRs are using Squash Commit message, as this GitHub action retrieves the source branch name from the Git Log of latest commit