# How to implement semantic versioning of Docker images in GitHub Actions workflow?

Tags: docker, github-actions, semantic-versioning

I would like to achieve the following CI pipeline with GitHub Actions workflow.

Pull Request is merged -> GitHub action is being triggered -> docker image is being built with semantic version incremented by one or the version is based on GitHub tag - if it is possible to somehow tag the pull request merge.

How to achieve that or is the better approach?

I have tried with secrets but no to avail. [How to implement semantic versioning in GitHub Actions workflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70925425/how-to-implement-semantic-versioning-in-github-actions-workflow)

Answer (score 3):

```
name: Docker Image CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]

jobs:

  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Build the Docker image
      run: docker build . --file Dockerfile --tag my-image-name:${{github.ref_name}}
```

`${{github.ref_name}}` pulls the tag for you or run git command like `git describe --abbrev=0`  in the previous step to get the latest tag and append it to image name and use it like:

```
- name: Get Tag
  id: vars
  run: echo ::set-output name=tag::${git describe --abbrev=0}
- name: Build the Docker image
  run: docker build . --file Dockerfile --tag my-image-name:${{ steps.vars.outputs.tag }}
```

Comment: set-output is deprecated command, env variables should be used instead - reference https://github.blog/changelog/2022-10-11-github-actions-deprecating-save-state-and-set-output-commands/

Answer (score 3):

You can use a lot of semver actions on the market place.
For example, I have tried using this -  [Semver action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/update-major-minor-semver)

This will bump your repo version, and you can use a git bash command to get that bumped version on the next job.

So combining with docker build, you can do something like:

```
jobs:
  update-semver:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: haya14busa/action-update-semver@v1
        id: version
        with:
          major_version_tag_only: true  # (optional, default is "false")
  Build:
    name: Build Image
    needs: [update-semver]
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Check out code
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Build image
      run: |
        tag_v=$(git describe --tags $(git rev-list --tags --max-count=1))
        tag=$(echo $tag_v | sed 's/v//')
        docker build -t my_image_${tag} .
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my public solution: a more or less trivial docker image, built and run during pull requests, bumping version based on commits when pushed to main. All based on the awesome work of others out there, i.e. using existing GitHub actions.

- docker QEMU, buildx, build-push-action
- https://github.com/addnab/docker-run-action to run/test the image
- https://github.com/anothrNick/github-tag-action to create a new tag before building and pushing it
- a "Release" workflow that depends on successful build and is only triggered on main.

details: https://github.com/DrPsychick/docker-githubtraffic/tree/main/.github/workflows

Answer (score 1):

I am using GitHubs `run_number` in conjunction with an action variable containing the major version number `1.0`.

After tagging the docker image with the version, e.g. `:1.0.1` as well as `:latest` I push the version tag back on the repo.

This requires you to allow writing to the repository but I feel that the added risk is worth it.

I use GitHub Container Registry to publish the packages generated.

```
name: Docker Image for GitHub Container Registry

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  build_and_publish:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - name: Echo version
        run: |
          echo Version is ${{ vars.VERSION }}.${{ github.run_number }}
      - name: Build and push image
        run: |
          docker login --username nielscastle --password ${{ secrets.GHCR_PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN}} ghcr.io
          docker build . --tag ghcr.io/castleandersen/somerepo:latest --tag ghcr.io/castleandersen/somerepo:${{ vars.VERSION }}.${{     github.run_number }}
          docker push ghcr.io/castleandersen/somerepo --all-tags
      - name: Create git tag
        run: |
          git tag ${{ vars.VERSION }}.${{ github.run_number }}
      - name: Push git tag
        run: git push origin ${{ vars.VERSION }}.${{ github.run_number }}
```